# Why is rewrite not allowed in htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

After converting to Apple Mavericks, .htaccess generates an error when the file includes reference to rewrite. What am I missing?

Error message from console says:

`[Wed Dec 04 22:41:52 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /Users/lewy/www/local.communityband.org/.htaccess: RewriteEngine not allowed here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your DOCUMENT_ROOT is `/Users/lewy/www/` You may try to use this to allow all configuration:

```
<Directory "/Users/lewy/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

So inshort you need to set `AllowOverride to All`

Comment: This apparently solved the problem. I put this into the users folder under lewy.conf.

Comment: I thought this solved the problem. I put this code into the users folder under lewy.conf. Unfortunately, adding rewrite code produced the same error. I'll go test some more.

Comment: I appear to have some other problem -- something crude like I can't spell. The answer above is, as expected, corrected as far as I can tell. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine` is not allowed in .htaccess, because the directory is not configured with the [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) `FollowSymLinks`.